# Xamarin Android app referenced to the dynamic shared library(.so) is looking for .dll extension

Tags: android, c++, xamarin, shared-libraries

I have a Visual C++ dynamic shared library (.so) project created using Xamarin. 
I am also creating a Xamarin.Android app in the same solution and trying to add the dynamic shared library project as a reference, so that I can debug into the c++ code.
I am doing this by selecting 'Add Reference' on the Android app project and bringing up the 'Reference Manager'. 
I see the dynamic library, check the box and hit OK.
The library gets added to the list of references with a yellow triangle indicating there is some problem. When I select it, I do see that the path property is empty.

I go ahead and build the project and I see in the Output window the following:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1550,2):
>   warning : Could not find file 'c:\users\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\MySharedLibrary\x86\Debug\libMySharedLibrary.dll'.

No wonder the error, it is looking for the library with "dll" extension instead of the "so" extension.

What do I have to do to make the Android app reference the dynamic shared library(.so) for debugging?

-Thanks

Edit:
I get the same error even with the SanAngeles demo project and the sample project on the MSDN blog.

Edit2:
Direct reference to the .so lib works, it is the project reference to native library that throws this error.

Comment: This might be a good starting point: http://kerry.lothrop.de/c-libraries/

Comment: You may want to compare your `.csproj` and `.sln` setup to the sample setup: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/using_native_libraries/#Debugging_Native_Code_with_Visual_Studio_2015 i.e.: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/SanAngeles_NDK/SanAngeles_NativeDebug/SanAngeles/SanAngeles.csproj#L84

Comment: Here's a good blog post on using C++ libraries with Xamarin Android: https://blog.xamarin.com/build-and-debug-c-libraries-in-xamarin-android-apps-with-visual-studio-2015/

Comment: Hi Jgoldberger, downloaded that applicaton yesterday and was having the same problem